# System of Equations in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, jupyter, equation

So, I am creating a linear system of equations calculator. I want the user to enter the number of equations in the system and the number of variables in each equation and then return the variables solved. My code is as follows:

```
    
def system_solve(y = None,c = None):
    import numpy as np
    
    z = []
    lefty = []
    for x in range(y):
        d = []
        for e in range(c):
            s = int(input(f"Constant {e + 1} of equation {y}: "))
            d.append(s)
        z.append(d)
        g = int(input(f'Sum of equation {x + 1}: '))
        lefty.append(g)
    

    right = np.array(z)
    left = np.array(lefty)
    return np.linalg.solve(right, left)

print(system_solve(int(input("# of Equations:")), int(input("Number of variables:"))))
```

When I run this code in Jupyter Notebook, I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LinAlgError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-378b544e77a6> in <module>
     20     return np.linalg.solve(right, left)
     21 
---> 22 print(system_solve(int(input("# of Equations:")), int(input("Number of variables:"))))
     23 

<ipython-input-25-378b544e77a6> in system_solve(y, c)
     18     right = np.array(z)
     19     left = np.array(lefty)
---> 20     return np.linalg.solve(right, left)
     21 
     22 print(system_solve(int(input("# of Equations:")), int(input("Number of variables:"))))

<__array_function__ internals> in solve(*args, **kwargs)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py in solve(a, b)
    397     signature = 'DD->D' if isComplexType(t) else 'dd->d'
    398     extobj = get_linalg_error_extobj(_raise_linalgerror_singular)
--> 399     r = gufunc(a, b, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
    400 
    401     return wrap(r.astype(result_t, copy=False))

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py in _raise_linalgerror_singular(err, flag)
     95 
     96 def _raise_linalgerror_singular(err, flag):
---> 97     raise LinAlgError("Singular matrix")
     98 
     99 def _raise_linalgerror_nonposdef(err, flag):

LinAlgError: Singular matrix
```

```
The input is something like this:
3
3
Constant 1 of equation 3: 4
Constant 2 of equation 3: 5
Constant 3 of equation 3: 3
Sum of equation 1 4
Constant 1 of equation 3: 5
Constant 2 of equation 3: 6
Constant 3 of equation 3: 7
Sum of equation 2 8
Constant 1 of equation 3: 9
Constant 2 of equation 3: 10
Constant 3 of equation 3: 11
Sum of equation 3 0
```

And The two "Right" and "Left" arrays are as follows:

```
Right:
[[ 4  5  3]
 [ 5  6  7]
 [ 9 10 11]]
Left:
 [4 8 0]
```

Can you please suggest edits to the code and help me fix this error?

Comment: What are your inputs?

Comment: @PriteshGohil, If I try any input, there is the same error

Comment: Show the `right` and `left` arrays.  When debugging this you need to clearly separate the processing of the `input` part from the `solve` part.  Get the parts right first.  Don't expect us to run your code with our own `input`.

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you. I am new to python and programming in general. You have helped me alot by giving me this tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

```
#Take input and solve system of equations
def system_solve(y = None,c = None):
    import numpy as np
    
    z = []
    lefty = []
    for x in range(y):
        d = []
        for e in range(c):
            s = int(input(f"Constant {e + 1} of equation {y}: "))
            d.append(s)
        z.append(d)
        g = int(input(f'Sum of equation {x + 1}: '))
        lefty.append(g)
    
    
    right = np.array(z)
    left = np.array(lefty)
    try:
    
        return np.linalg.solve(right, left)
    except np.linalg.LinAlgError as err:
        if 'Singular matrix' in str(err):
            return "Cannot Have a singular martix"
        else:
            return str(err)
print(system_solve(int(input("# of Equations:")), int(input("# of variables:"))))
```

The error was that I was giving a singular value to the matrix which means that there would be infinite solutions for the system.